# Javascript : function that involves two functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a function call "sendAndMove" that involves two function inside.
And I want two functions executed in order of setting() ---> goHome(). But when I wrote code like down below, it is exectued like goHome() ---> setting(). So I used async/await to achieve to goal.

Is this problem happend because of asynchronous feature and Call stack?
And I want to know why setting() function doesn't work if page changes.
Thanks a lot

```
function setting() {
        setFinalInfo((prev)=>{return{...prev,
          finalAddress: info.address,
          finalCode: info.code,
          finalDetailAddress: info.detailAddress,
          finalPostCode: info.postCode,
          finalExtraAddress: info.extraAddress}
        });
          
      }
      function goHome(){
        navigate("/")
      }
        
      function sendAndMove() {
        setting();
        goHome();
          
      }
```

So I Changed to code below.

```
  function setting() {
        setFinalInfo((prev)=>{return{...prev,
          finalAddress: info.address,
          finalCode: info.code,
          finalDetailAddress: info.detailAddress,
          finalPostCode: info.postCode,
          finalExtraAddress: info.extraAddress}
        });
          
      }
      function goHome(){
        navigate("/")
      }
        
      async function sendAndMove() {   ***** Changed this part
        await setting();
        await goHome();
          
      }
```

Comment: These functions definitely get called in the order you wrote them. However, it could be that `setFinalInfo` does something asynchronously, so you don't see the effects immediately after the function returns. Show the code of `setFinalInfo` and `navigate` if you want us to provide more help.

Comment: why do you await them? They are not async. Technically you can await any function but it doesnt have the the effect you might expect.

Comment: Umm.. Then because first setting( ) goes to call Stack and goHome() goes next The goHome( ) gets called first??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want to do is 'channel' from a callback to an awaitable promise, something like this:

```js
function setting() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setFinalInfo((prev) => {
      resolve({
        ...prev,
        finalAddress: info.address,
        finalCode: info.code,
        finalDetailAddress: info.detailAddress,
        finalPostCode: info.postCode,
        finalExtraAddress: info.extraAddress,
      });
    });
  });
}

function goHome() {
  navigate('/');
}

async function sendAndMove() {
  await setting();
  goHome();
}
```

Btw, you don't need to await on `goHome()` since that is not an async function.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal approach would be to set the state, and then use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to watch for a change in state and then call `navigate`.

```js
function update() {
  setFinalInfo((prev) => {
    return { ...prev,
      finalAddress: info.address,
      finalCode: info.code,
      finalDetailAddress: info.detailAddress,
      finalPostCode: info.postCode,
      finalExtraAddress: info.extraAddress
    }
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  navigate('/');
}, [finalInfo]),
```